# Obtener el valor de un atributo html y al dar clic en un boton mostrar ese valor en un modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

necesito ayuda con un pequeño detalle que tengo, tengo un foreach el cual me recorre los datos, por cada fila que se recorre hay un boton y a ese boton le creé un atributo llamado id_curso. La idea es que cada vez que se le de clic al boton de cualquier fila mostrar un modal y en el un formulario y por ende en un input mostrar el valor de ese atributo.

Actualmente estoy utilizando jquery

```
<div class="form-group row justify-content-center" >
    <button class="btn btn-warning btneditarcurso" id_curso="'.$value["Id_curso"].'" 
       data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarNota" style="margin: 2.5px;">
       <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

En resumen solo necesito que al dar clic tomar ese valor y mostrarlo en un input.

Agradecería mucho me iluminen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu pregunta es muy amplia y solo colocas un pequeño fragmento de código correspondiente al botón creado dinámicamente, basándonos en lo que preguntas que solo es mostrar el valor del atributo `id_curso`  en el modal, lo que debes hacer es:

1. Agregar una clase al button ej. id_curso
2. En js hacer uso del metodo `attr()` de jquery con el cual obtienes el valor del atributo de la siguiente manera `$(this).attr("id_curso");`
3. Ahora ya solo muestra el valor de tu atributo en el input del modal ej. `$("#txt_cursos").val(curso);`

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional que espero te ayude.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table_example").on("click", ".idCurso", function() {
    let curso = $(this).attr("id_curso");
    $("#txt_cursos").val(curso);
    console.log(curso);
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <table id="table_example" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Curso</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger idCurso" id_curso="Curso 1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Curso 1</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger idCurso" id_curso="Curso 2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Curso 2</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger idCurso" id_curso="Curso 3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Curso 3</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <input id="txt_cursos" type="text" name="txt_cursos" value="" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono perfectamente