# ¿Cómo paso un dato a la vista modal para realizar una consulta?

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-5

estoy trabajando con bootstrap 5 , php y una conexión a base de datos PDO.

Tengo una tabla que me bota una lista con información de los representantes, a esto le añadí un botón con el objetivo de al hacer click sobre este; me muestre en una ventana modal todas las prescripciones (solo visualizar) del representante.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí es donde surge el problema, ¿como paso el dato del representante que necesito a la ventana modal?; lo he estado intento de esta manera:

```
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#openprescrip" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-whatever="<?$pres->representante;?>">Prescripciones</button></td>
```

la ventana modal esta de esta manera:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="openprescrip" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="openscripLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="openscripLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
             </div>
          <div class="modal-body">        
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

y uso este script

```
   <script>
   var exampleModal = document.getElementById('openprescrip')
   exampleModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   // Button that triggered the modal
   var button = event.relatedTarget
   // Extract info from data-bs-* attributes
   var recipient = button.getAttribute('data-bs-whatever')
   // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here
   // and then do the updating in a callback.
   // 
   // Update the modal's content.
    var modalTitle = exampleModal.querySelector('.modal-title')
    var modalBodyInput = exampleModal.querySelector('.modal-body input')

    modalTitle.textContent = 'aqui debe ir el representante ' + recipient
    modalBodyInput.value = recipient
 })
  </script>
```

No me llega el dato, lo que me llega es todo el mensaje `<?$pres->representante;?>`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cambia esto `<?$pres->representante;?>`  por esto `<?=$pres->representante;?>` a ver si ahora si... no, tampoco te funcionara... mmm... seguro que ese cacho de código es interpretado como PHP?  parece que lo has puesto en alguna parte donde simplemente es html insertado que no se interpreta con PHP

Comment: Gracias ya me salio el nombre, ahora me concentrare en como le voy a consultar, algun consejo que me puedas dar, para hacer una consulta? por favor

Comment: Quizá esta que respondí en esta otra pregunta te ayude [Obtener el valor de un atributo html y al dar clic en un boton mostrar ese valor en un modal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/449719/obtener-el-valor-de-un-atributo-html-y-al-dar-clic-en-un-boton-mostrar-ese-valor/449874#449874)

Comment: @SantiagoTulcanazo no se a que te refieres con lo de la consulta.  Si el problema de esta pregunta esta solucionado y necesitas hacer algo más y no lo consigues, haz otra pregunta nueva. No se aceptan varias preguntas a la vez, lo siento.